# What is the simplest way to print every nth line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file (let's call it sample.txt) which consists of 750 lines of text. I would like to put the entire second line in a list, followed by every 8th successive line (ie then 10th, then 18th, then 26th and so on).

```
sam_file = open("sample.txt")
sam_lines = seq_sample.readlines
```

But then what? The iterative methods I've tried just grab the 2nd, 10th, etc characters from the first line, but I know it must be a fairly simple for loop.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is no longer relevant to me, as I asked it over 3 years ago when I was just starting out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this?

```
from itertools import islice
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    for line in islice(f, 2, None, 8):
        print line,
```

Comment: second line has index 1. And I don't like the 1-letter variable name

Answer (score 1):

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to the rescue:

```
with open('sample.txt') as sam_file:  # always open files with context managers
    sam_lines = itertools.islice(sam_file, 1, None, 8)
    # do your stuff with the context
```

Depending on what you would do with the content, you better keep the action within the context manager, or save the content of the file in memory (by doing a `sam_lines = list(sam_lines)` or so)